# Set max for a particular column of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there anyway to basically take a column of a numpy array and whenever the absolute value is greater than a number, set the value to that signed number.

ie.

```
for val in col:
    if abs(val) > max:
        val = (signed) max
```

I know this can be done by looping and such but i was wondering if there was a cleaner/builtin way to do this.

I see there is something like

```
arr[arr > 255] = x
```

Which is kind of what i want but i want do this by column instead of the whole array. As a bonus maybe a way to do absolute values instead of having to do two separate operations for positive and negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55127144/2954547) is good but it doesn't get you all the way there. Frankly, this is somewhat of a RTFM situation. But you'd be forgiven for not grokking the [Numpy indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) on your first try, because they are dense and the data model will be alien if you are coming from a more traditional programming environment.

You will have to use `np.clip` on the columns you want to clip, like so:

```
x[:,2] = np.clip(x[:,2], 0, 255)
```

This applies `np.clip` to the 2nd column of the array, "slicing" down all rows, then reassigns it to the 2nd column. The `:` is Python syntax meaning "give me all elements of an indexable sequence".

More generally, you can use the boolean subsetting index that you discovered in the same fashion, by slicing across rows and selecting the desired columns:

```
x[x[:,2] > 255, 2] = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling clip on your numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3])
values.clip(-2,2)

Out[292]:
array([-2, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a little late, but I think it's a good option:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3])
values = np.clip(values,-2,2)
```